# FocusPanel events only on the edges?

Tags: java, gwt

Is it possible to devide a FocusPanel into segments, and having each segment respond to a different geographic direction? And this only on the edge of the FocusPanel?

I want to stretch the FocusPanel all over the page, and only want mousOver responses when the mouse touches one of the Panel edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot divide a focus panel into segments. However you can simulate your own, something like this.

```
public class MyFocusPanel extends DockLayoutPanel
{
      private FocusPanel f1 = new FocusPanel();
      private FocusPanel f2 = new FocusPanel();
      private FocusPanel f3= new FocusPanel();
      private FocusPanel f4 = new FocusPanel();

      public MyFocusPanel ()
      {
           super(Unit.PX);
           f1.addClickHandler ( new ClickHandler() 
           {
               public void OnClick()
               {
                     onFocusPanelClick();
               }
           });
           f2.addClickHandler ( new ClickHandler() 
           {
               public void OnClick()
               {
                     onFocusPanelClick();
               }
           });
           f3.addClickHandler ( new ClickHandler() 
           {
               public void OnClick()
               {
                     onFocusPanelClick();
               }
           });
           f4.addClickHandler ( new ClickHandler() 
           {
               public void OnClick()
               {
                     onFocusPanelClick();
               }
           });

           addNorth( f1, 5.0 );
           addWest( f2, 5.0 );
           addEast( f3, 5.0 );
           addWest( f4, 5.0 );
}
```

Now add your widget into this using `add( Widget );` API